# Snarl or HTTP? Which protocol I should use to connect to remote Stardog server

Tags: java, sparql, stardog

I am new to stardog and I want to insert huge size data (in GB's) into remote Stardog server through java API's.
Stardog support connection via snarl and HTTP. Now I am confused about which I should choose.

I have two question:

1. What are the pros and cons of these protocols?
2. For better performance which protocol I should choose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNARL is an RPC protocol that uses Protobuf encoded messages for communication between the client and server. For small/short requests, like getting the size of the database, SNARL is usually faster due to less overhead.

At larger scales, 1G of data is 1G, and it doesn't matter which protocol you use, transport time will be the same.

The time it takes to parse, encode, and write the data into the database is likely going to dominate how long the operation takes, so in some sense it doesn't matter which protocol is used in terms of performance.

I recommend you use HTTP, performance is no worse and it's easier to use to communicate with the server in other languages, or tools like cURL.

Comment: Thanks. I do agree on points you mentioned. We have already taken decision to go with HTTP. :)